# How to add custom gradle task after generating classes.dex file during android build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex, android-build, android-build-type

I am trying to add one gradle task after generating classes.dex in android build.

i tried with `dexRelease/dexDebug` task that I got it from the below thread

[Gradle task for classes.dex CRC calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532628/gradle-task-for-classes-dex-crc-calculation)

but during Configuration phase, I can able to see the task but it's not executing.

i have added some logs in the `doLast` but its not printing. thats how i confirmed that its not executing.

```
tasks.all { task ->

    if (task.name == 'dexRelease') {

        println "-NAME: "+ task.name
        //task.finalizedBy taskAfterDex
    }

}


task taskAfterDex(type:Exec) {

   println "taskAfterDex configured"
    doLast {
        println "taskAfterDex executed"
    }
}
```

is `dexRelease/dexDebug` is the right task to detect the classes.dex generation?
or I need to use some other task to check dex generation

i have asked another question here related this.

[How to execute a gradle task after android dexDebug or dexRelease task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60612752/how-to-execute-a-gradle-task-after-android-dexdebug-or-dexrelease-task/60729839#60729839)

but first i nee dto know why dexRelease is not executing / is it the right task to check the dex generation

am checking the dex file in the below location during the build process.

```
/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug
```

Comment: Just in case you want to alter the DEX file, the standard way for doing that is [Transform API](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api).

Comment: @AlexLipov i dnt want to alter the dex file , i want to run i=one task immediately after the  dex creation.